# Django+Cython import cython module in django app views

Tags: django, cython

a newbie to django and Cython. I am creating an app in django and need to import function in views.py from cythonized module. following is views.py inside my app.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import sys
import numpy as np
import random
import math
from cython_node_val import node_val

def home(request):
    return render(request,'Home.html',{"name":"user"})

def shortest_path1(request):

    K=int(request.POST['number of layers'])
    if ((K%2!=0) or (K < 0)):
        return render(request,"shortest_path1.html",{'shortest_path1':"K must be an even integer"})
    else:
    ......
        
    Node_val=node_val(Hash,C,K) #node_val is from cython_node_val which is a .pyx file, Hash C and K 
                                are defined in body after else statement.  

    sPath=np.zeros((K,3))
    sPath[K-1,:]=Node_val[n-1,:]
    for m in range(K-2,-1,-1):
             sPath[m,:]=Node_val[int(sPath[m+1,1])]
    return render(request,"shortest_path1.html",{'shortest_path1':sPath[:,3]})'''
```

the directory of my project is like following:
[image: project directory Django]

my app directory looks like this
[image: app directory with built cython code and supporting files highlighted]

cython_node_val.pyx works fine when importing into a normal .py file, but when doing the same inside views.py in my app it throws me following error

```
File "C:\Users\amit\projects\application_shortest_path\shortest_path\DS2P\urls.py", line 9, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\amit\projects\application_shortest_path\shortest_path\DS2P\views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from cython_node_val import node_val
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cython_node_val'
```

I believe if views.py is a python file and we can do operations, it should pull cython_node_val and associated functions. Where am i wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: line 6 of the "view.py" you show is __not__ `import cimport`. That suggests the code you're running is not the same as the code in the question. I think you've just got confused about `cimport` though - it is a Cython mechanism for importing Cython modules at compile-time. Thus in Cython you would do `cimport module`. Unless you have a module called `cimport` then what you have done is meaningless

Comment: thanks @DavidW. i edited the error message. i wrongly put the error message. there is nothing about cimport. I am trying to import cython_node_val.pyx which is not recognized as its not a .py file. so my question is how to make use of functions in cython_node_val.pyx. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use os.getcwd() to debug where you are running from your script  views.py:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd()) 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cimport'
```

Then adjust the path to your needs

Is usually an error when you are trying to reference something that isn't in the python running path script + the path that you are giving inside your script.

Comment: thanks for the prompt response. actually the error msg i posted was wrong. the problem is with importing cython_node_val.pyx. So my question is why is it not working with views.py when it is normally working with other .py files. Is there something i have to do with model.py in django project directory or what changes i have to make so that views.py could identify cython_node_val.

Comment: i have edited the post with correct error message. thanks.

Comment: I found a solution which is to put the cython_node_val module put at project directory level and not at app directory level. so i had to move the file one level up. thanks.